# Flash plugin / youtube issue

Tags: 12.04, flash

Using Firefox and Chrome.
youtube wrking with HTML5 when flash plugin inactive.
but
youtube just stays still with black window, after loading the video, when using **flash plugin** to play it.

(why flash plugin needed isntead, if HTML wkring? HTML5 hangs quite long, the same video clip through the same internet connection working with no loading breaks on other devices (adnroid) suspect using flash plugin on them).

re-installed the plugin, exaclty the same problem

version flashplugin-installer 11.2.202.310ubuntu0.12.04.1
any suggestions? 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Google Chrome or Chromium? Anyway Google Chrome has already built-in pepperflash, which is basiclly the newest version of adobe flash player. 
I've installed flash player on Chromium using the link below:

[Install Pepper Flash Player For Chromium In Ubuntu Via PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-pepper-flash-player-for.html)

If you want to install the newest version of flash player for firefox, do the folowing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this lines helpful for version 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree sudo
update-pepperflashpplugin-nonfree --install sudo
update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

It installs other version of flash plugin which works.

On adobe.com page the last version for Linux is Version 11.2.202.394.
Linux platform is no longer supported.
Now the newest version is 14, so I recommend to use pepperflash plugin instead of your old version of flash.